# How an I import new components from node_modules into the project?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, webpack

When answering, you can safely talk as if I'm 5 years old because I'm in WAY over my head here (hello imposter syndrome). I have been using Webpack and WordPress for quite some time now, but I recently decided to add Vue into the mix to help me learn.

Problem is, I have no real clue what I'm doing. I successfully got WordPress and Webpack to include and use Vue, but that was only after 5 days of work, and I still really don't understand how it works. Now, while trying to use Vue, I installed [Flicking](https://naver.github.io/egjs-flicking/docs) with yarn. I'm familiar with yarn installs, but at this point I am lost. And with WordPress + Webpack + Vue, there's so many points of failure I don't know where to even start. Hoping someone can help.

Current error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../node_modules/@egjs/vue-flicking' at webpackMissingModule (frontend.js?ver=1.1:17476:50) at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[9].use[0]!./assets/src/stickyButton.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

File Structure (omitted files and folders that are outside the question scope):

```
.
└── theme-folder/
    ├── frontpage.php (where the component is being used)
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json (and lock files and such)
    └── assets/
        └── src/
            ├── sass/
            │   └── frontend.scss
            ├── js/
            │   ├── frontend.js
            │   └── header.js
            └── stickyButton.vue
```

### stickyButton.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <Flicking :options="{ renderOnlyVisible: true }">
        <div v-for="idx in list" class="flicking-panel" :key="idx">{{ idx }}</div>
      </Flicking>
      <div class="block is-flex is-justify-content-center">
      <span class="button mr-2 is-info is-outlined" @click="() => {
        list.splice(0, 0, ...[list[0] - 2, list[0] - 1]);
      }">Prepend</span>
        <span class="button mr-2 is-info is-outlined" @click="() => {
        list.push(list[list.length - 1] + 1, list[list.length - 1] + 2);
      }">Append</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as Vue from 'vue';
import VueFlicking from "../../node_modules/@egjs/vue-flicking";
Vue.use(VueFlicking);

export default {
  name: "stickyButton",

  data() {
    return {
      list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>
@import url("../../node_modules/@egjs/vue3-flicking/dist/flicking.css");
// Extra css code omitted
</style>
```

### Webpack compiles all the js and outputs in frontend.js:

```
// WP stuff
import "../sass/frontend.scss"
import "../js/header.js"

//start of vue stuff
import * as Vue from 'vue'
import Flicking from "@egjs/vue3-flicking";
import stickyButton from '../stickyButton.vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
const app = createApp(stickyButton)
app.mount('#stickyButton')
```

Long story short, nearly everything I search is now purple links from visited sites from trial and error and I don't even know where to look to figure this out. Is there an issue with calling flicking from the `stickyButton.vue` component? Is the issue in the way its called in `frontend.js`? Any help, insight, suggestions, articles, etc would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We're all in way over our heads because coding is a deep ocean. No one ever gets to the surface. :)

Comment: Don't use relative paths for node modules.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for [VueFlicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@egjs/vue-flicking) for local import would look like this:

```
<script>
import { Flicking } from "@egjs/vue-flicking";

export default {
    name: "stickyButton",
    components: {
        Flicking: Flicking,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And for styles:

```
<style scoped>
@import url("/node_modules/@egjs/vue-flicking/dist/flicking.css");
// Extra css code omitted
</style>
```

You may have to configure `webpack.config.js` to resolve the node_modules path:

```
// inside webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'), 'node_modules']
  }
};
```

See [webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules)